# What is "default location" for Struts actions (in config-browser)?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, web.xml, struts2-config-browser

I have been seen there is a "default location" for all my actions when debugging using the Struts plugin "config-browser". Something like the below one:

```
Action information - list*

Action name:    list*
Namespace:  
Action class:   listAction
Action method:  {1}
Parameters: 
Default location:   /mysite/list*.action
```

I'm wondering what is this "default location" means anything?
Can I change it? How can I change it?

BTW: I've changed my struts filter in `web.xml` to only listen to `/test/*` and `/action/*`. I'm not sure why it's still says the "default location" is `/mysite/list*.action`.

Comment: What are you debugging? Is this action mapping?

Comment: I mapped the action, just never heard of the concept of this "default location"

Comment: i will try something as you suggested next week (it's Friday)... and see if it is what you said...

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such concept "default location". There's "default action".

> Usually, if an action is requested, and the framework can't map the request to an action name, the result will be the usual "404 - Page not found" error. But, if you would prefer that an omnibus action handle any unmatched requests, you can specify a default action. If no other action matches, the default action is used instead.

If you look at the `ActionMapping` class you see that it has not the location attribute. Instead `ServletDispatcherResult` and `ServletRedirectResult` has such parameter. So, using it with mapping can figure out the final location.

there's also default namespace and default class concepts that is mentioned when calculating the final location.

Also, the term **location** could be treated as the path and map to the configuration file where the action is configured.

Comment: the "default location" is not what i "invented"... it just showed on the web page when using the struts plugin "config-browser"